# Multilingual website with PHP not working on live servers, only Vagrant

Tags: php, server, multilingual, production-environment

I am building a multilingual website with PHP and got it perfectly up and running in my Vagrant box changing texts according to the $SESSION[lang] variable, uploaded the site to my live server and suddenly the language doesn't change any more, it just sticks with the default language.

Here is the code I used to supply the site with the corresponding language files, which include associated Arrays with the texts I want to use in every language:

```
<?php
ob_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}


// language switch 

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && ($_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang']) && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if ($_GET['lang'] == "es")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "es";
    else if ($_GET['lang'] == "de")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "de";
}

require_once ('content/language/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php');
```

I have two different servers in development and production, not ideal I know. My Vagrant box:
Ubuntu Xenial 64 with PHP 7.0.32 & Apache 2.4.18

I updated my Live Server today to:
Centos 6.10 with PHP 7.1 & Apache 2.4

After the upgrade I restarted the apache server because I thought maybe that helps, but without success. As mentioned it just sticks with the default language and doesn't update when I click on any of the language switch buttons. In the dev environment it worked exactly as expected. I would really appreciate any ideas what might go wrong here, I am not sure where to look.

Thanks in advance!! Sarah.

Comment: does any session variable work?  
Could be a cookie issue or that on server side for some reason sessions are not stored (writing permission on /var/lib/php/sessions/ or php.ini not pointing to the right place) - note that if php runs in apache mod, this folder must allow www-data to write there

Comment: Good point Anthony, thanks! I tried to check on that and although it says in the php info file that session support is enabled it doesn't work correctly. Now I have to figure out how to resolve that, if you have any suggestions that would be so helpful!

Comment: could you find how and where sessions are stored?
Could you compare phpinfo() data between your two setups?

Comment: Yes I found out, but in the end resulted only being a comment I had left before starting the session in PHP. By removing it everything works now great. Thanks for your help! You lead me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found out the reason, just in case it happens to somebody else, I had a comment on the beginning of my page before the

```
ob_start();
```

and session start code.

The issue got fixed by putting it as the first thing in my file, with no blanc space, nothing before it. Found it out reading other threads here.

Thanks for contributing!